# "a belter of a game"

Tags: meaning

*FC Barcelona took on Atletico Madrid in massive top of the table clash in spanish league at Camp Nou and **it turned out to be a belter of a game**.*

Source: http://www.totalsportek.com/highlights/atletico-madrid-vs-barcelona-replay-video/

I would like to ask what noun stands in the pronoun "it" in the above sentence. I presume that it is "clash". But then the phrase "it turned out to be a belter of a game" sounds to me a little bit odd. The clash is the game so the game turned out to a belter of a game…

Comment: It's a (primarily *British*) colloquial expression meaning [an event, person, quality, etc, that is admirable, outstanding, or thrilling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/belter).

Comment: *Joe Schmo took on former champ Mikey Tykey, and **it** turned out to be a helluva fight.*  There, **it** has no explicit antecedent. It's a *dummy*.